# Web app for students marks management for college

Tags: web-apps, database, data-analysis

Currently we are using MsExcel to manage marks and results. I want to migrate to a Web app with MySql backend. Which software or platform or framework is better for me to start with?
I have many cohorts, exams,subjects, students, marks and grades. We also maintain marks at QUESTION level, like how much each student secured in each question.
I want data entry forms for teachers to enter and reports which are statistical charts and analyses that currently I developed using R.

Any recommendations please to help me managing students marks?